# dynamic convert using Type Class C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a type and object and I need to convert that object to that type.  Here is my sample code:

```
foreach (object o in eTable)
{
     var type = (typeof(ERPEntities).GetProperty(TableName).PropertyType);
     // this is the static conversion but i need the dynamic one to generalize the code
     var dasd = o as GN_Nationalities;
}
```

Comment: This isn´t possible, as the actual type is only known at runtime-time whereby a cast needs a static compile-time type.  What do you actually want to do? Can you introduce an interface which all your classes implement?

Comment: unfortunately i cannot because the classes came from the entity framework

Comment: Did you take a look at the [TypeConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class already? Maybe that can help you

Comment: What do you want to do with the casted instance? Even it it *would* be possible to cast at *runtime*, for the *compiler* `dasd` still was an `object`, making it impossible to access any of the members of the actual *runtime*-type. However you cpuld use reflection to do something with those members.

Comment: every o is a record in my table and I need to extract this records as list of table type (entity type) for example 
List<GN_Nationalities>